# PHP Fatal error: require()

Tags: php, web, smarty, host

I have a website that works perfect in my localhost with xampp, but... I uploaded it to a few free websites hosting (000webhost and hostinger) and when i try to open it, got this message:

> Warning: require(core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u327900732/public_html/www/index.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u327900732/public_html/www/index.php on line 7

This is the code:

```html
    <?php   

session_start();

$view = isset($_GET['view']) ? $_GET['view'] : 'index';

require_once('core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php');
require('core/models/class.Conexion.php');

if(file_exists('core/controllers/'.$view.'Controller.php')){
    include('core/controllers/'.$view.'Controller.php');
}else {
    include('core/controllers/errorcontroller.php');
}

?>
```

I checked that file one hundred times and it is there.

I found and tried this solutions:

- Changing Require for Include:

> Warning: include(core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u327900732/public_html/www/index.php on line 7
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u327900732/public_html/www/index.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Smarty' not found in /home/u327900732/public_html/www/core/controllers/indexController.php on line 3

- require(chdir(dirname(**FILE**)) . 'core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php');

> Warning: require(1core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u327900732/public_html/www/index.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '1core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u327900732/public_html/www/index.php on line 7

- Changing line 7 for
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php');

> Warning: require_once(/home/u327900732/public_html/core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u327900732/public_html/www/index.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/u327900732/public_html/core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u327900732/public_html/www/index.php on line 7

I tried adding './' to the path but it still doesn't work. I repeat, the site works perfect in my localhost. Help please!

Comment: Are the required (Smarty) files on the server?

Comment: If the file is actually on the server, you likely need to access via the core path where it sits on the server. Something like `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php');` will work. You might have to adjust this based on your directory design.

Comment: @user2182349 The Smarty files are in my main folder, and i uploaded the complete main folder to the server.

Comment: @camelCase thanks but it didn't work, I edited the post with your idea and its result

Comment: You refer to the files being in your _main folder_, is your main folder inside your `www` folder? In other words, if you add the `www` before `/core/libs/....` does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use complete url to test your url. Or check in your browser to check the file exist or not. Like here:

http://host.com/core/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php

I think it will show error that show your file isn't exist there.